# Installation on SONY VAIO VGN-FE690

Tags: installation, sony

I cannot install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Sony VAIO VGN-FE690. When it shows the window to type my name and password the window closes.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You might want to add how you're trying to install, USB, CD, etc, are you dual-booting, what are your laptop's hardware specifications? And whether you manage to run the installer and if it is on restart that there is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved after trying time after time to install Ubuntu every time the installation crashed on "who you are" after typing my name and password then trying over and over again it went well and I could end sucessfully my installation, I even try to install Fedora instead but it didn't even read my pen drive... hope it help other people!